# how to order results of LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

My LEFT JOIN query works fine but I encountered a problem on ordering the results of the query.

The query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.postId = comments.commentId 
ORDER BY postDate DESC, commentDate DESC
```

Instead the comments are pulled at the end of my listing.

POSTS

```
postId (Primary)    int(11)      AUTO_INCREMENT
postUserId          int(11)
postType            varchar(10)
postContent         text
postCaption         text
postState           varchar(10)
postVotes           int(11)
postDate            datetime
```

AND comments

```
commentId (Primary) int(11)     AUTO_INCREMENT
commentUserId       int(11)
commentFor          varchar(20)
commentForId        int(11)
commentContent      text
commentState        varchar(20)
commentVotes        int(11)
commentDate         datetime
```

From the query comments are not ordered properly
Raw data pulled from the database
first pulled from Comments

```
"1","1","post","1","this is one comment and the only one","published","1","2019-02-05 12:04:00"
```

And this is from Posts

```
"1","1","text","this is the first post",,"published","1","2019-02-05 12:02:00"
"2","1","text","this is the second post",,"published","1","2019-02-05 12:16:00"
```

Desired result should be like

```
"2","1","text","this is the second post",,"published","1","2019-02-05 12:16:00"
"1","1","post","1","this is one comment and the only one","published","1","2019-02-05 12:04:00"
"1","1","text","this is the first post",,"published","1","2019-02-05 12:02:00"
```

Ordered by date/ time

Comment: posts have somehow a priority and are displayed all at the beginning

Comment: `but i encountered a problem on ordering the results` which is? You've provided what happens, but we also need what you wanted.

Comment: `posts.postId = comments.commentId`? sure?

Comment: you mean that posts with no comments are shown first, or what? NULL fields are usually shown first in an ORDER BY. Give an example of the source data, the expected result, and also the result you currently get. Also `posts.postId = comments.commentId` looks like it's probably a mistake. Surely you want to link a post ID in one table to a post ID in the other table?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.postId`

Comment: so i have 4 posts records on my db posted yesterday, 1 comment record posted today and 1 post record posted also today and the comment record is among the posts that i posted yesterday

Comment: @DuduClau - please add your table structure (with data types) and some example data and your expected output. be careful if your `postDate` contains time.

Comment: @DuduClau Thanks, but a _description_ of your data is really not much help to us. It's like trying to fix a car's engine just from a description given over the phone, instead of looking at it yourself. As already mentioned by myself and Sebastian, please show us the actual raw tables and data, and the actual result you want to get from your query.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) (the one titled **How to write a good SQL question?**) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: i guess he want's an union of both tables and then order the result by date

Comment: how do i achieve?

Comment: achieve what? show us your wanted result table data.

Comment: @Dudu Clau Can you provide an example of what you want as the result?

Comment: @DuduClau You should use a UNION and nester query as my answer. See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koRapukYqcSxWLNQ8hSA7Y/1 ( first table result ). It is same as your desired result.

Comment: @niyou  Spot on... great comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First off

First off, you have an error in your join condition.

So, each post and each comment have a unique primary key. 
This means that you cannot join postId with commentId because a post can have many comments.. and every comment needs a different id.

So the correct condition is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.postId = comments.commentForId 
ORDER BY postDate DESC, commentDate DESC
```

### UNION with Nested Query and Order

Now, to combine and order the results of comments and posts you need to use a nested query and UNION.

Example:

```
select * from

(select postId as entryId, postContent as content, postDate as timestamp from posts
UNION
select commentId, commentContent, commentDate from comments)temp

ORDER BY temp.timestamp DESC;
```

With Data:

```
create table posts(
  postId int,
  postContent text,
  postDate datetime
  );

  create table comments(
    commentId int,
    commentForId int,
    commentContent text,
    commentDate datetime);

    insert into posts values (1, 'this is the first post', "2019-02-05 12:02:00");
    insert into posts values (2, 'this is the second post', "2019-02-05 12:16:00");

    insert into comments values (1, 1, 'this is the comment', "2019-02-05 12:04:00");
```

See the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koRapukYqcSxWLNQ8hSA7Y/0

Comment: not working comment is the last and the two posts are above

Comment: @DuduClau Update for more fields. You should be close to there if you just modify any minore things you need: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koRapukYqcSxWLNQ8hSA7Y/2 . `select * from

(select postId as entryId, postUserId, "text", postContent as content, postState, postVotes, postDate as timestamp from posts
UNION
select commentId, commentUserId,  "post", commentContent, commentState, commentVotes, commentDate from comments)temp

ORDER BY temp.timestamp DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN` conditions are suspicious:

```
posts.postId = comments.commentId
```

This would suggest that ids with very different names should be matching.

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*   -- you should list the columns you want
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     comments c
     ON p.postId = c.postId 
ORDER BY p.postDate DESC, c.commentDate DESC;
```

I'm not 100% sure this will fix your ordering logic, but this should at least return a more reasonably result set.  That said, I would want to keep the posts in order by post as well as date, so I would use:

```
ORDER BY p.postDate DESC, p.postid, c.commentDate DESC;
```

This will keep comments on posts that have the same `postDate` together.